# How to use sz commands on two linux system

Tags: linux, ssh

A <--ssh--> B <--ssh-->　C , The computer A can NOT copy file to  C with scp directly.
I have install lrzsz in the computer C. How to transfer files between A and C.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`nc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) installed on `B` then you can use `B` as a proxy and connect from `A` directly to `C` using:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand "ssh user1@B nc %h %p 2>/dev/null" user2@C
```

Replace "user1" and "user2" with your login names on the respective computers.

Replace the outer `ssh` with `scp` and `user2@C` with the source and destination files using the syntax accepted by `scp` and you're good to go!
For example:

```
scp -o ProxyCommand "ssh user1@B nc %h %p 2>/dev/null" user2@C:file1.txt .
```

copies `file1.txt` from your home directory on `C` to the current local directory.

---

I didn't actually test the command lines as exposed above. For both `ssh`/`scp` commands I also added `-i` with the path to my private key to avoid `ssh` and `scp` asking for passwords.

To make the things pleasant to use, you can write in your `~/.ssh/config` on `A` something like this:

```
Host = B
User = user1
IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_dsa_B

Host = C
User = user2
IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_dsa_C
ProxyCommand = ssh user1@B nc %h %p 2>/dev/null
```

Replace in the sample above "user1" and "user2" with your actual login names on the corresponding machines and "id_dsa_B" and "id_dsa_C" with your private key(s) you use for the two machines. I assume you know how to generate and use public/private keys.

Then you can simply use:

```
ssh C
scp C:file.txt .
```

Answer (score 0):

If B's ssh server allows port forwarding, you can do, for example,

```
A$ ssh -N -L10022:C:22 B
```

and leave that running, then in a seperate shell,

```
A$ scp -P 10022 file.txt localhost:
```

Read more about [ssh port fowarding](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+port+forwarding). You don't have to use port 10022, any unused port will work.